# UE4 Shoot Projectile BluePrint - Projectile spawns but doesn't move

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am trying to shoot different projectiles based on which weapon is currently selected. The projectiles spawn but don't move anywhere. I currently have 2 projectile BluePrints (Parent and child):

```
BP_Projectile (Parent)
BP_PistolBullet (Child)
```

The parent class has a float called ProjectileSpeed. I have set the value of the float in the child class to 5000.0 for testing.

For the moment the child class contains a Cylinder with a box collision just so I can see something render. I have enabled 'Simulate Physics' on the cylinder.

I have then created an array called `CollectedWeapons` in my character blueprint with a type of `BP_Projectile` and added a single element with the value set to the class of `BP_PistolBullet` (I know a projectile isn't a weapon, but thats going to be expanded later :P )
[image: CollectedWeapons Array]

The rest can be seen in my 'Shoot' BluePrint:
[image]

If you need any more information please let me know. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

BP_PistolBullet components as requested.

[image: BP_PistolBullet Components]

EDIT:

Trying to make projectile shoot forward, but can't get it right. I've tried multiple different things, but this is the latest attempt:
[image]

Comment: Could you show how 'BP_PistolBullet' components looks like in 'Components' tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because you tring to access Cylinder Static Mesh component by using "Get Child Component" node. "Get Child Component" returns one component from set of directly attached components. When you enable physics simulation on component it is [automaticly detached](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/270783/enabling-physics-on-subcomponent-detaches-componen.html) from it's parent component, so it could behave independently. It leads to situation when simulated components are not present in results of "Get Child Component" of your "Default Scene Root".

You could solve it quickly by saving physicaly simulated child component to some variable present in BaseProjectile. But I think perfect design will be to use ["Projectile Movement Component"](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Components/Movement/) in base blueprint or to apply force directly in blueprint in "BeginPlay" event.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I will try your suggestions tomorrow after work and let you know how I get on :)

Comment: I like the look of the 'Projectile Movement Component' and what it can do. I've tried adding it to the parent and child classes (1 at a time) but neither make the projectile move. I saw a tutorial which says you have to set the mesh as the scene root which in this case would need to be set as the root of the parent class. But I want to be able to create different projectile types (E.g. bullets, rockets etc) so I would need a different mesh for each type. Is that possible or would I need to use another method?

Comment: When I was working on my simple projectiles I've disabled 'Simulate Physics' and made simple, small collision box as root of components tree. Simple physics is ensured by Projectile Movement Component (e.g. Should Bounce" property). In derived blueprints you could use collision box as an anchor and attach to it different meshes or other collision boxes.

Comment: Thank you that works, but my last problem is that the projectile is shooting down through the floor instead of forward in the direction my camera/player is facing. I'm trying to calculate the look rotation to make it shoot in the correct direction, but I can't get it right. I've tried several ways but nothing seems to have any effect. I have added a screenshot of my latest attempt to the question.

Comment: Make sure your projectile X axis is pointing forward and Projectile Movement Component has "Velocity" set towards X axis. Then, you could just directly use camera rotation as initial transform when spawning projectile.

Comment: I solved the last problem. I didn't realise but projectile gravity was set to 1 by default and my initial speed and velocity wasn't enough to see it move forward before going through the floor lol. Thank you for your help.